# refactor duplication of SELECT inside CASE inside SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to refactor this select statement to remove duplication

```
select
    (
      case
      when (
        select my_product_int_attribute -- duplication
        from app_public.products
        where product_id = entry.product_id
      ) > 0 then 1
      when (
        select my_product_int_attribute -- duplication
        from app_public.products
        where product_id = entry.product_id
      ) = 0 then 0
      else null
      end
    )
from app_public.entries as entry
where entry.project_id = 1;
```

are there exists easy options without joins, maybe something like `with` statements that can be used inside select?

N.B.

project has many entries, entry has one product

Comment: Why no joins?  I'd be surprised if a join performed worse than those correlated subqueries.

Comment: The `sign()` function would let you map all positive values into a single value (1) and use a simple searched `case (<subquery>) when 1 then 1 ...` that requires no duplicated expression. Or just `sign((<scalar subquery>))` if negative values are impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be use CTE instead?

```
;with products as (
select products.product_id, products.my_product_int_attribute 
    from app_public.products
    group by products.product_id, products.my_product_int_attribute 
)
select
(
  case
  when products.my_product_int_attribute > 0 then 1
  when products.my_product_int_attribute = 0 then 0
  else null
  end
)
from app_public.entries as entry
left join products on products.product_id = entry.product_id
where entry.project_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sign()`:

```
  nullif(sign( (select p.my_product_int_attribute
                from app_public.products p
                where p.product_id = entry.product_id
               ) 
             ), -1
          )
```

However, a `left join` -- such as sgeddes (now deleted) answer -- seems like the right approach.